# custom error handler that would take effect only in my class?

Tags: php, oop, error-handling

Or do I must call `set_error_handler()` on beginning and `restore_error_handler()` on end of every of my methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily.

When your error handler returns false, it will continue to the next registered error handler. (usually the php default error handler).

So you could write your function in a way it only handles specific - custom written - error codes.

```
function newErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (checkIfyours) {
        // Do something.
    }
    return false;
}
```